# How can I animate the size of UILabel or UITextField text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, core-animation

I have a UITextfield in a UIView that contains some default text. I want to animate the scaling of this textField (along with the parent UIView) %300, and later back down to 100%.

How do I do this? It seems everything I've found involves a hacky image capture and a CGAffineTransformMakeScale.

I've spent way to much time searching SO for this, either it's difficult and/or costly to do or utterly trival to implement. I wouldn't be surprised if it's the latter. :)

Comment: Do you want to change the frame's size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to capture the image from the view, you can simply use scale transform on your label using the following code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But the only problem with this approach is that the text might not appear crisp.

If you want the scaling of your `UILabel` to be crisp than I suggest you try core text framework. This will definitely help you in achieving your goal.

A tutorial for the same can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app).

Comment: You can now use blocks for UIView animations :
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
       label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0);
 }]

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Animations-Explained](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/animations-explained.html)

[ios/documentation/CoreAnimation_guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
animation.keyPath = @"position.x";
animation.values = @[ @0, @10, @-10, @10, @0 ];
animation.keyTimes = @[ @0, @(1 / 6.0), @(3 / 6.0), @(5 / 6.0), @1 ];
animation.duration = 0.4;

animation.additive = YES;

[form.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shake"];
```

OR

[iOS - Animating text size change in UILabel or UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376676/ios-animating-text-size-change-in-uilabel-or-uitextview)

This might helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.1

Using `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` does not work for FontSize. and using `CGAffineTransform` is hard to manage, and has to be applied to the `UILabel` or `UITextField`, but as it is said in the accepted response, the result is not crisp.

This is the solution I am using.

```
var fontSize: CGFloat = 12.0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    self.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: fontSize)
    fontSize += 0.5 // Or 0.333 to allow for 3X resolution screens.
    if fontSize > 17.0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```